# How to calculate angle deviation for points in ArcGIS and QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcmap

I want to calculate angle deviation point layer ( Electricity Towers). I found Generate Near table tool in ArcGIS but it only calculates angle between two points. In that case I need to give temporary points and calculate for 3rd one.

Any tools or methods to calculate?

I am attaching screenshot of it. In Generate Near by tool I am getting angle for each point , but I want the angle between point no 4 and 5.

How do I get that?

[image]

Comment: Your question title and tags specify QGIS, but the question body only mentions ArcGIS. Please choose one software stack or specify that you are trying to reproduce one with the other, and remove the ArcGIS tag.